# Passing props using createApp

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

I'm using Vue3 on a Rails app and struggle with passing the props using composition api:

Rails part:

```
<% props = {
    id: @estimate.document_no_f
  }.to_json
%>

<div id="invoice_app" data="<%= props %>"></div>
```

main.js

```
const element = document.getElementById("invoice_app")
const data = JSON.parse(element?.getAttribute('data') || '')

console.log(data); <-- {id: 'A-00014'}
if (element != null) {
    const app = createApp(
    DragDropZone,              <-- Component
    {
      props: ['id']
    },
    {
      id: data.id
    }
    ).mount('#invoice_app');
}
```

DragDropZone component:

```
props: {
    id: String,
},
setup(props) {
    console.log(props); <- undefined
```

How would I pass the props to the component in the createApp function properly?

Comment: All I know is that you use `props` vue internally to pass data from your parent to your child. In your case, is it possible to import data differently? Maybe from a script?

Comment: @wittgenstein I used it with options api like this. So it is possible - but don't know how to do this with composition api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have passed `DragDropZone` as the first argument to [`createApp`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#createapp) method, which is wrong. The first argument is `props` & second is your `prop` data. Components need to be registered separately, like I've shown below. You can refer to [component registration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html) page to learn more about component registrations in `vue3`

Coming to your issue of not being able to receive the props in child component, you need to first pass the props to the child component in order to get them in the `composition` api.

ex. `<drap-drop-zone :id="this.id"></drap-drop-zone>`

Only then you will be able to get this in the child component like this:

`setup(props){ console.log(props); }`

**So correct the following line from this:**

```html
<div id="invoice_app" data="<%= props %>"></div>
```

**To this:**

```html
<div id="invoice_app">
   <drap-drop-zone :id="this.id"></drap-drop-zone>
</div>
```

###### Sample implementation

```js
const data = {
  id: 'A-00014'
};

const app = Vue.createApp({ props: ["id"],}, data);

app.component('drap-drop-zone', {
  template: `
    <div>
      Output from drap-drop-zone: {{ this.id }}
   </div>
  `,
  props: {
    id: String
  },
  setup(props){
    console.log(props);
  }
});


/**
// or require it from a file
import drapDrop from '/../.../DragDropZone.vue';
app.component('drap-drop-zone', drapDrop);
**/

app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <drap-drop-zone :id="this.id"></drap-drop-zone>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this too, like: `{ props: ['id']},  { id: data.id }` but it's still undefined.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you an example. Seems to be working for me.

Comment: I updated the question, how I am trying it right now. It seems to be similar... Only difference is the component I'm passing to createApp

Comment: can you show me how you have passed props to your `DragDropZone` component in the template?

Comment: Everything I did is shown in the question. There is no extra DragDropZone-Tag. The component gets rendered, just the props dont work.

Comment: yeah, there should probably be a line like `<DragDropZone :id="this.id"></DragDropZone>` which passes the data to the component as props.

Comment: If I add  `<DragDropZone :id="id" /> between the div tags, it doesn't change anything.
`

Comment: hold on, let me create a working example..

Comment: Thank you very much! It really was the component registration in the end. =)